# PHP/IIS copy()/move_uploaded_file() failed to open stream: Permission denied Warning

Tags: php, iis, file-upload, warnings, file-permissions

I am relatively new to web development and currently ran into an error I can't solve.

I use IIS to test my php after typing in "http://localhost/index.html" and select the example file to upload, it generates the following warnings:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/Angela_Nie_resume_technical - EditedMW.doc): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php on line 26
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php74F2.tmp' to 'upload/Angela_Nie_resume_technical - EditedMW.doc' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php on line 26
```

Below is the code that is related with moving my files.

```
$target_dir = "upload/"; 
$target_file = $target_dir . basename( $_FILES["uploaded"]["name"]) ; 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target_file))  {
    echo "The file has been uploaded"; 
}  
else { 
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading file."; 
}
```

I am using Windows 8.1 and using IIS to run localhost. Thank you in advance for helping me out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that user who is running the apache server does't have write permissions for `upload/` directory. You can right click the folder and set permission for writing to everyone.

**Update**

It might be because your PHP is in *safe mode* and doesn't execute commands like *move one file to another*. Check your **php.ini** for `safe_mode` and `safe_mode_exec_dir` and experiment with them.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I have already done that for every possible folder that the program may touch and it's still not working.

Answer (score 8):

In my situations, the IUSR account needed permissions in the destination directory. Not the ISS_IUSR account, just the IUSR account.

Comment: Worked like a charm. How did You know by the way? How one can find correct user IIS will use to execute php code?

Comment: Unfortunately, it was trial and error on my part. I don't know how to look up that information.