# Issue with photo upload to server and database

Tags: php, html, mysql, upload

I'm having an issue doing photo uploads on my site.

I'm getting my last error message ("Please select a file to upload") at the `$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);` line and there's no insert to the database or upload on the server.

I'm wondering if there could possibly be an issue with my insert as I'm trying to insert the file name but then also the url by doing 'images/' plus the filename. All images are to be uploaded in the images directory so I want to make sure the URL always has the 'images/' in the front.

I'm not sure what else could be going wrong here but maybe I'm missing something

Here's the form and the php script:

```
<form action="uploadImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formControl">Upload Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="formControl">
    <input type="submit" name="fileUpload">
  </div>
</form>

$statusMsg = '';

// File upload path
$targetDir = "images/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
            // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = $mysqlConn->query("INSERT into images (image_name, url) VALUES ('".$fileName."', 'images/".$fileName."'");
            if($insert){
                $statusMsg = "The file ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully.";
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
            } 
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, & PDF files are allowed to upload.';
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}

// Display status message
echo $statusMsg;
```

Comment: your file input is missing a name: `name='file'`

Comment: Ah, I did miss that. Unfortunately still getting the message "Please select a file to upload" but this time it doesn't state that specific line

Comment: and did you fix the submit as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your validation, you should revise your html markup like this:

```
<input type="file" name="file" class="form-control-file" id="formControl">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

Or change your condition of validation to

```
if (isset($_POST["fileUpload"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
   ...
}
```

Anyway, `name="file"` is needed for your file input element.

Comment: Ok I've changed that but I now get " move_uploaded_file(images/sofa4.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied" on the line ```if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){```

Comment: Try changing to: `$targetDir = getcwd() . "/images/";`, if still not working, check your directory permission.

Comment: I made my images folder full access for 'users' but still this
```move_uploaded_file(C:\Websites/images/sofa1.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Websites\uploadImage.php on line 21 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpA067.tmp' to 'C:\Websites/images/sofa1.jpg' in C:\Websites\uploadImage.php on line 21```

Comment: Not really sure the actual problem, you may refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127789/php-iis-copy-move-uploaded-file-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-war

Comment: If my answer fixed your question `get an error message ("Please select a file to upload")`, please accept it. Thanks.

Comment: it did and I accepted it but can you look at my insert? I'm apparently not concatenating 'images/' to the filename variable properly because if I add that in it fails

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180169/discussion-between-chaska-and-tom-n).